# Run commands inside a container already running

Tags: docker, command, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I'm using docker executor with DinD, and I was wondering if it's possible to send commands to a container already running in the background.

Comment: A Docker container is just a wrapper around a single process; does your setup allow you to run multiple commands inside the same process otherwise?  What's wrong with creating new containers?

Comment: @DavidMaze Let's say that a container is idle waiting for new commands to run. This container should take only one command at a time.

The problem is not creating a new container but to download for each job the same image which make my pipeline run slow.

Comment: "New commands" how; via a message queue or HTTP POST requests?  You should not normally need to re-download the same image every time you run it, and I might focus on trying to fix that problem.  (Docker-in-Docker adds some complexity here and the setup may be clearer if you can remove that from the stack.)

Comment: ""New commands" how"

That's basically my question in this post. it looks like that with the command `docker exec` I'll be able to execute commands in a bash terminal of the running container.

Comment: "You should not normally need to re-download the same image every time you run it, and I might focus on trying to fix that problem. "

I was under the impression that when using Docker executor with DinD you need to pull the image you're working on from a registry on each job since the containers for the Docker executor and DinD are restated in each job.

Comment: "(Docker-in-Docker adds some complexity here and the setup may be clearer if you can remove that from the stack.)"

So, you're suggesting not to use DinD? and instead use the docker engine from the host pc?